# Doctrine 2 QueryBuilder add multiple select elements /parameters?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I am still struggling with doctrine QueryBuilder as I think it is not working properly when I want to add another element into a select expression .

In this both situations doctrine $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResults() is returning an array where entities are represented as a string instead of objects :

Situation 1 :

```
$queryBuilder = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder->select("e, 99 as number");
```

it returns

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
     array(2) {
        [0]=> string(30) "Profile_Entity" //notice this is a string but it should be  an object instance 
        ["number"]=> string(2) "99"
     }
  ...
...
```

if i will write

```
$queryBuilder = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder->select("e");
$queryBuilder->select("99 as number");
```

It will return the same things as situation 1

Below is how it should normally be ( here is just one element in select expression  )

```
array(4) {
  [0]=> object(stdClass)#935 (39) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=> string(30) "Profile_Entity"
    ["id"]=> int(46)
    ["headline"]=> string(7) "asdasd
    ...
  ...
...
```

Answer (score 9):

I was struggling with a similar problem.

The answer I found was relatively simple..

```
$queryBuilder -> select('table.column1 alias1, table.column2 alias2');
```

You seperate by using a comma, and use a space after the column to put the alias of the column.

EDIT:

You can't mix objects with values. You can only do one of these:

```
$qb -> select('tableAlias1', 'tableAlias2')
$qb -> from('table1','tableAlias1')
$qb -> leftJoin('table2','tableAlias2');
```

OR

```
$qb -> select('tableAlias1.column1', 'tableAlias2.column1')
$qb -> from('table1','tableAlias1')
$qb -> leftJoin('table2','tableAlias2');
```

You will have to specify each column that you want to retrive from each table if you decide that you need to extract certain columns on top of a table.

Comment: what i you want to select all from tableAlias1 for example?