# Assign multiple distinct Entities to one Array row in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

When I execute something like this in Doctrine:

```
$qb = $doctrine
  ->getRepository('EntityA')
  ->createQueryBuilder('a')
  ->addSelect('b')
  ->join('EntityB', 'b', 'WITH', 'a.b = b')
  ->getQuery()
  ->getResult()
```

I get an array that looks like this:

```
array(0 => EntityA,
      1 => EntityB,
      2 => EntityA,
      4 => EntityB)
```

In fact, I get 2 result rows, but an array which has a size of 4. This makes iterating over it for displaying in templates nearly impossible.

I would like a result like this:

```
array(0 => array(EntityA, EntityB),
      1 => array(EntityA, EntityB))
```

Of course I could create a mapping on `EntityA` that references `EntityB`. But even with the possibility to change the loading behavior, `LAZY`, `EAGER` etc., it could be desirable to have the possibility to create such relations on the fly.

For example:

In overviews with large amounts of Entities, `EAGER` loading is needed to prevent excessive amounts of queries. But when I want to display only one Entity and do not need the extra data, LAZY loading is more desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `EntityB` mapped as `EntityA.b`, as indicated by this relation:

```
...join('EntityB', 'b', 'WITH', 'a.b = b')...
```

Thus you do not need in fact to add `b` to the select as you are loading it either ***eagerly*** or ***lazily***.

Remove `->addSelect('b')` from your query builder and use `EntityB` trough your `EntityA.b` mapping.

**Example:**

```
$as = $doctrine
    ->getRepository('EntityA')
    ->createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->join('EntityB', 'b', 'WITH', 'a.b = b')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();

foreach($as as $a){
    echo "EntityA property".$a->id;
    echo "EntityB property".$a->b->id;
}
```

This query will return an `ArrayCollection` of `EntityA`.

***Note:*** The example above assumes that `EntityA.b` is a public property.

**Update:**

After some digging I found this older post: [Doctrine 2 QueryBuilder add multiple select elements /parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13645880/2853903). According to it you can get the result you wan by directly separarating the entities with commas instead of using the `->addSelect()` method.

Try the following DQL:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT a, b FROM EntityA a JOIN a.b b")
```

The query above will dynamically eagerly fetch `b`.

Comment: So I still map `EntityB` to `A`, say via Annotation, lazyly. By joining manually I imitate an eager fetch? Doctrine recognizes the fetched data and sets it to the according field on `EntityA`? That would be neat...

Comment: @Joshua actually after researching a bit more the topic I found that I was wrong. According to official documentation: `A join (be it an inner or outer join) becomes a “fetch join” as soon as fields of the joined entity appear in the SELECT part of the DQL query outside of an aggregate function. Otherwise its a “regular join”.`

Comment: @Joshua I'll research the topic a bit more today and suggest a different solution.

Comment: thank you very much for your efforts. Unfortunately, your suggestion results in the described behaviour, an array containing alternating entities. I guess that the current version of Doctrine does not support what I have in mind.